# Creating a public class in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

*waves* So, I'd like to create a class in one file, and access it in another. The class acts as a handler for other functions in the project.

Main file

```js
"use strict";
const Cluster = require("./Handler.js");

exports = function (e) {
    // Some kinds of stuff, but I'll just skip to the class call.
    return new Cluster.Object(e); // "ReferenceError: Cluster.Object is not a constructor"
}

// Execute for testing.
exports(["foo", "bar"]);
```

Handler

```js
const Obj = require("./lib/Object.js");
const Str = require("./lib/String.js"); // Dummy

class Cluster {
    Object(e) {return new Obj(e)} // I'm sure it will happen here too, that error.
    String(e) {return new Str(e)}
}

exports = Cluster;
```

lib/Object

```js
class Obj {
    constructor (e) {
        this = {
            element:  e,
            instance: instanceof e
            length:   e.length
        };
    }

    get instance() {return this.instance}
    get length()   {return this.length}


}

exports = Obj;
```

Comment: I think you're trying to access instance variables (Object) in Main file without first creating an instance.

Comment: How to do I change it so it'll access the methods?